# Laravel covert integer to 12 hour format in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

is there any way to convert hour from int to 12 hour format? I store the hour as int in database because Im using it for javascript, but want to show it as 12 hour format in blade view without using controller
for Now Im using this in view

```
Open Hours: {{$allstore->store_open}}:00 - {{$allstore->store_close}}:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the int value to DateTime

```
Open Hours: {{ date('h:i a' , strtotime($allstore->store_open.":00")) }} - {{date('h:i a' , strtotime($allstore->store_close.":00"))}}
```

I would suggest using mutators in your model, which will always return you the desired format

```
public function getStoreOpenAttribute($value)
{
    return  date('h:i a' , strtotime($this->attributes['store_open'].":00"))  ;
} 

public function getStoreCloseAttribute($value)
{
    return  date('h:i a' , strtotime($this->attributes['store_close'].":00"))  ;
}
```